# Unable to install AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

```
sudo gdebi AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 

Adobe Reader allows you to view navigate and print PDF files. This version adds advanced forms support (save), better integration with Adobe Acrobat workflows, customizable toolbars and better overall performance.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
(Reading database ... 245373 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb ...
Unpacking adobereader-enu (9.5.5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/bash_completion.d/acroread.sh', which is also in package acroread-bin 9.5.5-1precise1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get remove acroread-bin` first.

Answer (score 1):

There is a conflict. Remove the package `acroread-bin` first

```
sudo apt-get remove acroread-bin
```

After that, start the installation again

```
sudo gdebi AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```